# Eager Loading with Pagination

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-pagination

I have a a `group` instance I want to eager load with pagination:

```
public function show(Group $group)
{
    $group = $group->with('members);
    return$ group     
}
```

I want to return `group` with `members` paginated.

Comment: Which do you want paginated? Groups or members?

Comment: I wanted to paginate members but I have already figured it out @G.Baghashvili

Answer (score 2):

Use `setRelation()` and lazy loading:

```php
public function show(Group $group)
{
    return $group->setRelation('members', $group->members()->paginate(5));
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this eager load the relationship? I see no evidence of that here.

Comment: @Stephan-v It doesn't, but in this case, lazy and eager loading produce the same result. It's not possible to use eager loading the way the OP is trying to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but it's not recommended because using paginate for eager loaded relationships generates two repeated queries

```
public function show(Group $group)
{
     $group = $group->with(['members' => function($query) {
        $query->paginate(24);
    }]);

     return $group;
}
```