# Multiple Eager Loading With Pagination in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I want to return paginated data of the eager loaded relations so as I can display them using pagination in my view template

```
public function show(Group $group)
{
    $data = ['members', 'assets', 'liabilities', 'loans','shares'];

    $group = $group->load($data);

    return view('admin.groups.show', compact('group'));
}
```

This is my Group Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Group extends BaseModel
{   
    use Enumable;

    public function constitution()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Constitution::class);
    }

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
    }


    public function assets()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Asset::class, Meeting::class)
        ->orderByDesc('meeting_id')
        ->orderBy('member_id');
    }

    public function loans()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Loan::class, Member::class)
        ->orderByDesc('meeting_id')
        ->orderBy('member_id');
    }

    public function shares()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Share::class, Member::class)
        ->orderByDesc('meeting_id')
        ->orderBy('member_id');
    }

    public function liabilities()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Liability::class)->latest();
    }
}
```

I need to paginate $data array

Comment: show your Group model (and its load function)

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/q/54646763/4848587?

Comment: That was for one relation and now I have multiple relation that I have to eager load them @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: The solution is the same. You loop over `$data` and call `setRelation()` for every relationship.

Comment: Can you give me example, I have tried that with no lack @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setRelations()`:

```php
public function show(Group $group)
{
    $group->setRelations([
        'members', $group->members()->paginate(5),
        'assets', $group->assets()->paginate(5),
        'liability', $group->liability()->paginate(5),
        'loans', $group->loans()->paginate(5)
    ]);

    return view('admin.groups.show', compact('group'));
}
```