# Paginate eager loaded relationships results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i am trying to paginate a relationship result set by using a code very similar to this

```
<?php

class MainController extends Controller {

    public function show(Main $main)
    {
        $main = $main->with([
            'secondaryMorph' => function ($query) {
                $query->orderBy('ocurred_at');
                $query->paginate(50);
            }
        ])->first();

        return view('main.show')->with(compact('main'));
    }
}
```

But when this part of the view's code run a exception is thrown:

```
<td colspan="3">Mostrando {{ $secondary->count() }} de {{ $secondary->total() }}</td>
<td colspan="3">{{ $secondary->links() }}</td>
```

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::total does not exist.

How can i use eager loading with pagination?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54657233/4848587.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
$main = $main->first();
$secondary = $main->secondaryMorph()->paginate();
return view('main.show')->with(compact('main','secondary'));
```

And then in blade :

```
<td colspan="3">Mostrando {{ $secondary->count() }} de {{ $secondary->total() }}</td>
<td colspan="3">{{ $secondary->links() }}</td>
```